# Backbone.history.start throwing Error : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm trying integrate backbone into my project. But I'm not able to get the router object to work.

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "todo/:id" : "getTodo",
    },
    getTodo: function(id){
        console.log("You are trying to reach todo " + id);
    }
});

App.router = new App.Router();
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

The line Backbone.history.start is throwing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' backbone.js:1388
```

It's this line of code in the backbone file:

```
Backbone.$(window).on('popstate', this.checkUrl);
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you don't have `JQuery` loaded before `backbone`. Try to put jquery before backbone.js.

Comment: of course JQuery is loaded how do you think  $(function() {} is working otherwise?